# How to call the "Sound Setting" via command line in Windows

Tags: batch-file

My Windows PC connected to some sound devices and I always need to switch them. I can only open the Settings\System\Sounds and Click the "Sound Panel" in right side(I do not using English windows and the words may be wrong). After that I can switch the audio to be heard on other devices.
Is there other quick way to do this? I think there should be some command like 'devmgmt.msc'

Please help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this:

```
control.exe mmsys.cpl sounds
```